# How to create a reference to arrays and boost::array (or ideas to not have to)?

Tags: c++

I have

```
int valA[3] = {290, 340, 390};
int valB[3] = {160, 200, 240};

boost::array<myStruct, 4> myStructA = {{{250,8}, {170,8}, {70,8}, {30,3}}};
boost::array<myStruct, 4> myStructB = {{{50,4}, {110,6}, {220,6}, {270,8}}};
```

and I want to avoid copy and paste when doing the following:

```
if(useA) {
  // do a lot with valA and myStructA
}
else {
  // do a lot with valB and myStructB
}
```

So the idea is to have something like that (warning, non-working code inside):

```
if(useA) {
  int &val[3] = valA;
  boost::array &myStruct<myStruct, 4> = myStructA;
}
else {
  int &val[3] = valB;
  boost::array &myStruct<myStruct, 4> = myStructB;
}
// do a lot with val and myStruct
```

Is there any way to do so? Or is the general approach not good and there is a much cleaner solution?

I know of the rule "no arrays of references", but this should be a reference of an array... Or is it the same in the end?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why create references, why not put the code in a separate function and pass the arrays as parameters? `do_a_lot(valA, myStructA); do_a_lot(valB, myStructB);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int (&val)[3] = valA;`

(You need the `&` to refer to `val` rather than `int`).

`boost::array<myStruct, 4> &myStruct = myStructA;`

(Template parameters are part of the type, not the variable name).

Also it needs to be `int (&val)[3] = useA ? valA : valB;` or equivalent, since in your example code you're planning to use `val` outside its scope.

Answer (score 4):

For arrays, the syntax is

```
int (&val)[3] = valA;
```

For a UDT like `boost::array` it's simply

```
boost::array<myStruct, 4>& myStruct = myStructA;
```

Answer (score 4):

That won’t work: after the `if`s the references `val` and `myStruct` are no longer in scope.

You *can* use the conditional operator though:

```
int (&val)[3] = useA ? valA : valB;
boost::array<myStruct, 4>& myStruct = useA ? myStructA : myStructB;
```